# Как правильно поступить с неполными входными данными функции

Tags: javascript, typescript

не очень понимаю как правильно поступить с хуком в который могут поступить не полные данные. А конкретно:

Данные:

```
type IContent = { title: string; content: string }[];
const content = [
  {
    title: "Tab 1",
    content: "content 1",
  },
  {
    title: "Tab 2",
    content: "content 2",
  },
];
```

Код хука:

```
export const useTabs = <T>(initTab: number, content: T, key: string) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(initTab);
  if (content && Array.isArray(content)) {
    const currentTab = content[currentIndex][`${key}`];
    return { currentTab, setCurrentIndex };
  } else {
    throw "Error";
  }
};
```

Код использования:

```
const { currentTab, setCurrentIndex } = useTabs<IContent>(0, content, "content");
```

Проблема в случае если мы получаем прокидываем в content пустой массив [].
TypeScript ругается:

TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'unknown'

Поэтому применил приём с проверкой наличия контента, однако получается на мой вгляд косо.
Ведь я не хочу чтобы программа падала потому что был закинуть пустой массив (допустим пришло добро с сервера)
Как обработать и правильно вернуть значение хука и сеттер?

Comment: а в чем смысл записи `\`${key}\``  если `key` и так строка?

Comment: @Grundy, По причинам описаным выше typeScript  также ругался и на этот параметр.
Поэтому я попытался костыльнуть это таким образом.
Но проблема на другом уровне как я понимаю.

Comment: какая версия typescript? На playground не получилось воспроизвести ошибку

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/usetabs-yp1p6?file=/src/App.tsx

Тут немного другой код, я маленько эксперементировал.
Но суть проблемы осталась таже.
Не понятно как верно обработать это

Comment: Если подставить твой код - ошибки нет: https://codesandbox.io/s/usetabs-forked-9kb3t?file=/src/App.tsx